# Java - Difference between library and native library

Tags: java, jdbc, native

Could anyone tell me the difference between library and native library in terms of java? I found the word "native library" in the following line:

> Type 1 - drivers that implement the
>   JDBC API as a mapping to another data
>   access API, such as ODBC. Drivers of
>   this type are generally dependent on a
>   native library, which limits their
>   portability. The JDBC-ODBC Bridge
>   driver is an example of a Type 1
>   driver.

which you can found [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Native Library" generally means a non-Java library that's used by the system (so C/C++, etc).  Think normal DLLs or libs.

Java can load these native libraries through JNI.

Comment: Can java load .dll files through JNI?

Comment: Absolutely.  I've only done it with DLLs specifically designed to work with JNI, so I'm not sure if you can load any DLL, but it's generally not too difficult to create a JNI wrapper for a normal native library (annoying busywork, but not generally hard).

Answer (score 5):

In the context of Java, a library is one written in Java and available in the form of Java bytecode *.class files, typically compressed into a JAR archive. By contrast, a native library is one that has been compiled to machine code and is typically written in C or C++. Native libraries are *.so, *.dylib, *.dll, *.a, or *.lib files (depending on your platform) that link against the Java Native Interface (JNI) library and expose  the functionality from C or C++ to Java through the Java Native Interace mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

A native library is a library that contains "native" code. That is, code that has been compiled for a specific hardware architecture or operating system such as x86 or windows.

Including such native library in your project may break the platform-independence of you application.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "library" is assumed to refer to a library written in Java (and probably distributed as a jar) whereas "native library" refers to a library written in something like C or OpenForth and compiled down to machine code.